# How to restore Alienware boot animation after dual booting with Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, bootloader, windows-10

I have Alienware 17 R3. I have dual booted with Ubuntu 16.04.

Now when I select windows in grub menu, the generic windows 10 animation shows up with 1024x768 resolution. Is there a way to restore my Alienware boot animation?

I have a feeling that it may be restored if I simply replace grub2 with Windows10 bootloader? If this will solve, how can I do that? My laptop is in UEFI mode.

Thank you.

Comment: GRUB is launching the Windows boot loader. It's conceivable that passing an option to the Windows boot loader will change its behavior, but I don't know what option might be required. (`sudo efibootmgr -v` should show the options used by each boot loader, but they're encoded in UTF-16. Once decoded, adding the relevant options to what GRUB passes to the Windows boot loader *might* work, but I make no promises about that.)

Comment: How can this be decoded? : http://pastebin.com/ffitjWUk

Also one more thing to note is that windows 10 animation was actually all garbled and entire screen was purple except the circling dots. So I searched for solution and found that this happens because of mismatch between grub resolution and windows 10 logo resolution.  So I lowered grub resolution to 1024x768 only to be welcomed by the generic win 10 logo at that above specified resolution. So could this be because of changing the grub resolution?